# Sql and Play Framework Date Issue

Tags: date, playframework-2.0, timezone

I have a form in which uses bootstrap date-picker. So when I save the form, the date object in the request header goes as `Sat Apr 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)` and from the server side it is saving one day back. I know it is related to TimeZone. I tried setting play's `application.conf` as

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbName?useGmtMillisForDatetimes=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC".
```

But it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please try to offer a *bit more* useful information than *it didn't work* ......

Comment: it is setting setting the date as one day back.